# How do I use a DataGridCellsPanel in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm relatively new to wpf....I have a default grid in my Xaml page and within that some standard labels and textboxes. I have now introduced a Border tag for one section of the page and within that I want a standard grid type layout with col1 being a label and col2 and col3 being text boxes. I thought I'd be able to use the `DataGrisCellsPanel` control, but I'm having difficulty with this. Can anyone point me towards a good Xaml example on how to achieve my layout.

Comment: Please add more info, code example or other about your problem

Comment: That's just it I haven't really got any code as I cannot get it to work at all, that's why I asked for a code sample as I'm clearly using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the default grid and set columns and rows manually:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="col1"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="col2"/>
    <Label Grid.Column="2" Content="col3"/>

</Grid>
```